# Get the cell number from double clicking on it and put it into another formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

As part of my ICT work we need to create a battleship game and one way I was thinking of doing it was using

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*x*",C3)),"HIT","MISS")
```

to check if that cell contains x but obviously it would be static and always checks C3. I need to search C3:G8 but if I do

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*x*",C3:G8)),"HIT","MISS")
```

It will search all of those cells and all of them have to contain an x, or not, to return HIT or MISS.

I was thinking if you double click a cell for example D4 it will take D4 and drop it into the formula almost for like a dynamic formula. Is that even possible?

Am I approaching this the wrong way and if so what would be a better way of approaching it?

Thanks

Comment: No, you can't really make double-click do anything other than double click. You could select a cell and press a button..

Answer (score 0):

"Dynamic formula" as you describe would require VBA. I have included a method to get you started - it allows the user to enter coordinates and find out if they have a HIT or MISS.

[image]

The formula being used in result cell is:

```
=IF(INDEX(C3:D5,MATCH(H3,B3:B5,0),MATCH(I3,C2:D2,0))="x","HIT","MISS")
```

To make it more readable (as it is homework...), I'd be tempted to use named ranges and thus:

```
=IF(INDEX(grid,MATCH(H3,y_axis,0),MATCH(I3,x_axis,0))="x","HIT","MISS")
```

.

**UPDATE**

Here is another similar - simple method, which uses conditional formatting to show hits and misses:

[image]

The conditional formatting uses simple formulas as following:

```
=AND(B3="x",H3="x")  //for a hit

=AND(B3="x",H3="")   //for a miss
```

The formula for hits remaining is as follows:

```
=COUNTIF(H3:L16,"x")-SUMPRODUCT((H3:L16="x")*(B3:F16="x"))
```